# Embedding a table view inside a table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my table view custom cells are used. Each cell need to be expanded and a list of details need to be shown for each cell item. This is dynamic and the number of details could only be known at run time. So is it possible to embed another table view inside each cell? I have not seen any where such an implementation. What will be impact ? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented this concept and it is possible to place a tableview inside custom tableview cell.

Comment: Here is a good example of what you want https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/adding-a-uitableview-inside-a-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using a `UITableView` in this instance, perhaps you might consider using a `UICollectionView` - they are built for something like you describe more than a `UITableView`. Or, switch to a different `UITableViewCell` (or multiple of them) be telling the `UITableViewController` to add cells or reloading the section (and reflecting the changes in your model).

Comment: How it could be accomplished with a collection view?